# fs-extra: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am receiving the following error using [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra#copy):

> ERROR { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\Projects\xxx\branches\xxx\release']   errno: -4048,   code:
>   'EPERM',   syscall: 'unlink',   path:
>   'C:\Projects\xxx\branches\xxx\release' }

When using this code in my node application:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');
fse.copySync('../util/various/a.html', '../release');
fse.copySync('../util/various/b.html', '../release');
```

I would like to know, what could cause the error and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

fs-extra doesn't support copying a file to a directory.

This will work:

```
const fse = require('fs-extra');
fse.copySync('../util/various/a.html', '../release/a.html');
fse.copySync('../util/various/b.html', '../release/b.html');
```

This is as-designed (https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra/issues/320) although I am here because I ran into the same issue.

Answer (score -2):

The module can't remove the destination file because of file's permissions (read-only).

Comment: Thanks ... but fse.copySync() is for copying only and removal for my understanding is not involved.

Comment: pardon, my bad. I was talking about the `destination` file. It's because it exists already.